# C++ understanding lambda mutable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, mutable

Ok, as explained [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293603.aspx) mutable specification makes available to modify copies of external variables, and that original variables (not copies) will not be modified.

So I tried next:

```
const int elementCount = 4;
    std::vector<int> v(elementCount, 1);
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    cout << "x 1 = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y 1 = " << y << endl;
    std::generate_n(v.begin() + 2, elementCount - 2, [=]() mutable throw() -> int {

        // Generate current value.
        int n = x + y;
        cout << "x 2 = " << x << endl;
        cout << "y 2 = " << y << endl;

        // Update previous two values.
        x = y;
        y = n;
        cout << "x 3 = " << x << endl;
        cout << "y 3 = " << y << endl;
        return n;
    });
    cout << "x 4 = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y 4 = " << y << endl;
```

Log:

```
x 1 = 1
y 1 = 1
x 2 = 1
y 2 = 1
x 3 = 1
y 3 = 2
x 2 = 1
y 2 = 2
x 3 = 2
y 3 = 3
x 4 = 1
y 4 = 1
```

and I was wondered that values of copied variables are saved from call to call. And I assumed that some instance variables for lambda object were created. And that instance variables were modified, and that is why values of copied variables are saved from call to call.

And to check my assumption I did following:

```
 const int elementCount = 4;
    std::vector<int> v(elementCount, 1);

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    cout << "x 1 = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y 1 = " << y << endl;
    // Assign each element in the vector to the sum of the
    // previous two elements.

    auto lambda_gen = [=]() mutable throw() -> int {

        // Generate current value.
        int n = x + y;
        cout << "x 2 = " << x << endl;
        cout << "y 2 = " << y << endl;

        // Update previous two values.
        x = y;
        y = n;
        cout << "x 3 = " << x << endl;
        cout << "y 3 = " << y << endl;
        return n;
    };

    std::generate_n(v.begin() + 2, elementCount - 2, lambda_gen);
    cout << "second calls group" << endl;
    std::generate_n(v.begin() + 2, elementCount - 2, lambda_gen);
    cout << "x 4 = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y 4 = " << y << endl;
```

so, there is only one instance of lambda_gen, and I thought that values of copies x and y
could be saved from first call of std::generate_n to second.
But output is:

```
x 1 = 1
y 1 = 1
x 2 = 1
y 2 = 1
x 3 = 1
y 3 = 2
x 2 = 1
y 2 = 2
x 3 = 2
y 3 = 3
second calls group
x 2 = 1
y 2 = 1
x 3 = 1
y 3 = 2
x 2 = 1
y 2 = 2
x 3 = 2
y 3 = 3
x 4 = 1
y 4 = 1
```

there are not saved from call to call! Why? Why there are saved from call to call inside of std::generate_n, and there are not saved when I call std::generate_n twice? Pelase help me,
how `mutable` specification works in lambdas?

Comment: I believe algorithms are allowed to copy their functor arguments.

Comment: @Mat Are they make copy of lambda, and in fact, there are works with those own copies? Is my assumption that some instance variables for lambda object were created right? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I checked that! Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the "standard" way to work around those copies is to use reference wrappers around your lambda when you pass it to an algorithm (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref). But I'm not very familiar with the details.

Comment: @Mat: Why don't you post this as an answer, a perfectly correct explanation of what is going on here.